# How to normalize histograms in joinplot margins

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, jointplot

How can I normalize the histograms in `sns.jointplot`?

Right now I'm getting this plot

[image]

However, instead of showing 0, 200, 400 on the axis, I would like it to be a fraction of the total number of the dataset

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
sns.set(style='white')

# sample x & y: doesn't match the top sample image
x = np.random.exponential(70, 100)
y = np.random.exponential(0.005, 100)

g = sns.jointplot(x, y, xlim = [30, 800], ylim = [0.0007, 0.023], marker = '*', s = 10, color = 'k',
             ec = 'k', marginal_kws=dict(bins=10, fill = True, log_scale=True), 
              height=1, ratio=6, marginal_ticks=True)
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color="r", zorder=0, levels=10, fill = True, thresh = 0.1)#, cmap = 'jet')

g.ax_joint.invert_xaxis()
g.fig.set_size_inches(14,10)
g.ax_joint.axvline(x = 70, color = 'red', ls = '--', lw = 2)#, label = '70 K')
g.ax_joint.axvline(x = 650, color = 'red', ls = '--', lw = 2)#, label = '70 K')
g.ax_joint.axhline(y = 0.005, color = 'red', ls = '--', lw = 2)#, label = '70 K')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As stated in [`seaborn.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html), `marginal_kws` should accept parameters from the type of plot in the margins (e.g. `sns.histplot` in this case).
- From [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html): **`stat='probability'`**: or proportion: normalize such that bar heights sum to 1.

  - Pass this parameter to `marginal_kws`
- If you want the total area of the histogram to equal 1, then use `'density'`.
- If there are multiple groups of data from using `hue`, then also consider adding `common_bins=False` and `common_norm=False` to `marginal_kws`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10` and `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# test data
np.random.seed(365)
x = np.random.exponential(70, 100)
y = np.random.exponential(0.005, 100)

# plot
g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y,  marker='*', s=10, color='k', height=7, ec='k', marginal_ticks=True,
                  marginal_kws=dict(bins=10, fill=True, log_scale=True, color='r', stat='probability'))
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color="r", zorder=0, levels=10, fill = True, thresh = 0.1)
g.ax_joint.invert_xaxis()
```

[image]

---

- Instead of using `xlim = [30, 800]` and `ylim = [0.0007, 0.023]`, which truncates the plot, you can mask the data first.

  - Both masks are applied to `x` and `y` to ensure the resulting datasets are the same length.
- This is optional, depending on how the data should be presented, and the bins will be normalized only on the selected data.

```py
# test data
np.random.seed(365)
x = np.random.exponential(70, 100)
y = np.random.exponential(0.005, 100)

# masks
x_mask = (x > 30) & (x < 800)
y_mask = (y > 0.0007) & (y < 0.023)

# selected data
x_sel = x[x_mask & y_mask]
y_sel = y[x_mask & y_mask]

# plot
g = sns.jointplot(x=x_sel, y=y_sel,  marker='*', s=10, color='k', height=7, ec='k', marginal_ticks=True,
                  marginal_kws=dict(bins=10, fill=True, log_scale=True, color='r', stat='probability', common_bins=False, common_norm=False))
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color="r", zorder=0, levels=10, fill = True, thresh = 0.1)
g.ax_joint.invert_xaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: Should probably have been in the original question, but do you also happen to know how to add labels to the histograms?

Comment: @JohnGoodWill That's really a separate question. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/73395291/7758804. Feel from to upvote that question and answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `g.ax_marg_x` and `g.ax_marg_y` to access the axes objects corresponding to the marginal distributions. Then you can iterate over [`Axes.get_children()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html) to filter out the "bar" objects which are represented as [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html). Then the height/width of these rectangle objects can be adjusted and the axes limits can be adjusted as well:

```py
import matplotlib.patches


def normalize_marginal(joint_grid, dim):
    get_size = lambda bar: getattr(bar, f'get_{"height" if dim == "x" else "width"}')()
    set_size = lambda bar, val: getattr(bar, f'set_{"height" if dim == "x" else "width"}')(val)
    set_lim = lambda ax, val: getattr(ax, f'set_{"y" if dim == "x" else "x"}lim')(val)

    ax = getattr(g, f'ax_marg_{dim}')

    bars = [obj for obj in ax.get_children() if isinstance(obj, matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)]
    sizes = [get_size(bar) for bar in bars]

    for bar, size in zip(bars, sizes):
        set_size(bar, size / sum(sizes))

    set_lim(ax, [0, 1])  # customize (e.g. `set_lim(ax, [0, 1.2*max(sizes)])`)


normalize_marginal(g, 'x')
normalize_marginal(g, 'y')
```