# How to add bar value annotations in jointgrid margins

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations, jointplot

- How can bar labels be added to the tops of bars in the x and y margins of a [`seaborn.joinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) or [`sns.JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html)?
- How can `matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`, as shown in [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804), be applied to the bars in the margins?

```py
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
planets = sns.load_dataset('planets')

# plot
g = sns.jointplot(data=planets, x='distance', y='orbital_period', color='purple', marginal_ticks=True, marker='.',
                  marginal_kws=dict(bins=10, fill=True, log_scale=True, color='purple', stat='probability'))

g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color='purple', zorder=0, levels=10, fill=True, thresh=0.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The margin axes must be used to annotate bars in the jointplot

  - `g.ax_marg_x`
  - `g.ax_marg_y`
- This is only a viable option with one group of bars (because of crowding); not with `hue=`.
- The linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) in the OP has additional details about [`maptlotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which don't need to be restated here.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

  - `.bar_label` is available from `matplotlib 3.4.0`
  - Assignment expressions (`:=`) are available from `python 3.8`

    - `[v.get_height().round(3) if v.get_height() > 0 else '' for v in ax_xm.containers[0]]` without `:=`.

```py
planets = sns.load_dataset('planets')

g = sns.jointplot(data=planets, x='distance', y='orbital_period', color='purple', marginal_ticks=True, marker='.', height=7,
                  marginal_kws=dict(bins=10, fill=True, log_scale=True, color='purple', stat='probability'))

g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, color='purple', zorder=0, levels=10, fill=True, thresh=0.1)

# alias for the x margin; this is not necessary, just used for conciseness
ax_xm = g.ax_marg_x

# only add labels if the value is greater than 0
xm_labels = [h.round(3) if (h := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in ax_xm.containers[0]]

# annotate the bar
ax_xm.bar_label(ax_xm.containers[0], labels=xm_labels, label_type='edge', rotation=90, padding=4)

# alias for the y margin
ax_ym = g.ax_marg_y

# only add labels if the value is greater than 0
ym_labels = [w.round(3) if (w := v.get_width()) > 0 else '' for v in ax_ym.containers[0]]

# annotate the bar
_ = ax_ym.bar_label(ax_ym.containers[0], labels=ym_labels, label_type='edge', padding=3)
```

[image]